# Return DataRow whose field is the max for specified column

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

I want to be able to get a datarow from a datarow array where the datarow has the maximum value for a specified column in all of the datarows.

I imagine it would follow suit to this LINQ statement

```
Dim minRow As DataRow = myDataRows.AsEnumerable.Min(Function(row) row.Field(Of Decimal)("myColumnName"))
```

However the Max function returns a decimal instead of a datarow. Is there some easy syntax that handles such a query for me?

And before anyone asks, I tag c# since in winforms they can easily be converted between each other using a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/), this can easily be done using `MaxBy()`:

```
var maxRow = myDataRows.MaxBy(r => r.Field<Decimal>("myColumnName"));
```

But using regular *Linq*:

```
var minRow = myDataRows.OrderBy(r => r.Field<decimal>("myColumnName")).FirstOrDefault();
var maxRow = myDataRows.OrderBy(r => r.Field<decimal>("myColumnName")).LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: Can the regular Linq be used to find both max and min?

Answer (score 1):

A little late but I want to share it anyway ;), you can do it in O(n) instead of O(n*log n) (which is the order for `OrderBy` extension method) if you use `Aggregate` extension method:

```
var minRow =myDataRows.Aggregate(myDataRows[0],(seed,next)=>next.Field<decimal>("myColumnName").Field<decimal>("myColumnName")?next:seed);
```

Check if your `myDataRows` array have at least one row

Comment: Thanks for the answer I upvoted you for it. But the syntax is more important since this is for a end user app that does not have strict performance requirements. Easier code readability trumps performance in this question.